# Are there posibilities for someone to break into my computer other than having installed malware first?

Tags: linux, macos, security, virus, malware

Mostly interested about OS X, GNU/Linux. Assume a default configuration, not too weak, not too hardened.
Exclude downloads of malware or physical access to computer to install malware.

Comment: Define "break into my computer". But the short answer is **yes, it's possible.**

Comment: Sitting at any computer is the best way to get into it. Your question needs clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Your question can't be answered as you have written it.  You're asking if something is possible. Things are only impossible until they're not.

Can a person break into your room if you've locked the door? Can someone steal your car if they don't have the key? Can pigs be made to fly? The answer to all three is *tehnically, yes*... if someone really really wanted to.

The goal of security is not to keep bad people from doing bad things. It's simply to make the reward not worth the effort.  Nothing will stop a determined adversary.  That's the only thing in this discussion that's *actually* impossible.

In their default configurations, all three major operating systems are hardened against typical attacks in the same way locking up your room/car/pigpen will deter the typical thief.  Beyond that, you'd have to ask a specific question to get a specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Assuming that what you mean by breaking into a computer means someone gaining unauthorized access... Then yes.

For elaboration think of it this way (one of many possible scenarios). 
Any system that provides a means for an authorized user to access can also be 'broken' into by an unauthorized user. The likelihood then comes about based on what the mechanisms for access are, what security you have in place, etc.

For example:
If you allow remote access to your system and set a really secure password like 'passw0rd' for that access (sarcasm), then it would be very easy to break into that system. If you have a computer off of all network connections (physical and wireless) and the only way to access the computer is by sitting in front of it and entering in that password... then it can still be broken into (understanding that someone first needs to break into your house).

Of course there are other ways in... such as bugs in applications, services, etc., that may allow access. Example: You throw up a web server and do not have any type of login, forms, etc. But you do not properly protect the SQL backend that a script accesses and someone can gain data from your DB through SQL injection... this is not malware, you did not actually present a means for authentication, and yet you still left yourself open.

So in a vacuum without any details on the type of setup you are thinking about the answer is simply yes.